# Running a query shows error on AWS Redshift "Queries" dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have to run a query to copy data from s3 to redshift.
Total size of the data to copy 110GB
Query runs fine for 1-2hr after that i see this error

```
There was an error retrieving the details for this query: Invalid Input. Expected Input: Load Id NOT_NULL, Load Status NOT_NULL
```

Query:

```
copy prod_data from 's3://my-buckets/prod-data/'  
access_key_id ''
secret_access_key ''
region 'eu-central-1'
delimiter ','
MAXERROR 100000;
```

Error snapshot: 
[image]

Please suggest how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Redshift console seems to be a little flaky at times, so you can't really "solve" this issue.

However, you can work around it and find out what's going on with your load.  All the web console does is read from Redshift's built-in system tables, so you can query these directly and get the information using your SQL client instead.

The stl_load_errors table contains details of any errors encountered during your data loads (i.e. the COPY command).  You can find out more information about this here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html

If you want to check the status of queries that are executing, or have previously been executed, you can also use the stl_query table: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html

Comment: In that case, try using stl_query to find out the results of your query. I'm guessing your target table "prod_data" doesn't have any records in it? Stl_load_errors only keeps records for a short while, so it suggests that either there wasn't an error with your load at all (the error was in the console only) or the record has dropped out the stl_load_errors table, in which case, re-running the copy command should repeat the error and give you a row in the table. Also check the output from your SQL client, because if there's an unhandled exception, it may show up there in the output.

Comment: Thanks, will try and let you know.